# laravel groupby is working on my local, but not on live server

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by

I am grouping data to show in graph using groupBy(). it is working on my localhost but when I pushed the code to live site then it throws isn't group by error.

**Error.**

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dds_sa.appointments.date_time' isn't in GROUP BY**

**Code:**

```
public function dailyReports(){
     return DB::table('appointments')
        ->select(DB::raw("
        sum(case when status = 'scheduled' then 1 else 0 end) as scheduled,
        sum(case when status = 'complete' then 1 else 0 end) as complete,
        sum(case when status = 'sold' then 1 else 0 end) as sold,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%W %M %e %Y') as date"))
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date_time')
        ->get();
}
```

**.ENV**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=db_name

DB_USERNAME=user_name

DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
```

**DB Default Settings:**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

**Can anyone guide me the solution of it ?**

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.appointments.date_time' isn't in GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled. You disable it using this command:

```
mysql > SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```

To see a list of enabled modes, run:

```
mysql > SELECT @@sql_mode
```

In the config, also change:

```
'strict' => false,
```